# Show that there exists infinitely many $n$ such that $u_n$ is not a perfect square

Tags: sequences-and-series, integers, square-numbers

Let $a, b, c$ be positive integers. Define the sequence $u_n$:
$$u_n = a \cdot 2^n + b \cdot 5^n + c$$
Show that there exists infinitely many $n$ such that $u_n$ is not a perfect square.

Source: Local exam for specialized students.

Comment: Four such questions in an hour. Just how special are you?

Comment: I usually wait until I have 3-4 unsolved problems before I post them.